# MeteorJS add nonce to inline CSS

Tags: javascript, meteor, content-security-policy

I have a a lot of inline CSS that is being used in one of my applications. When applying CSP, I had to force the use of 'unsafe-inline' which is being flagged down by vulnerability tools.
I would like to add a nonce to my inline css files in order to remove the 'unsafe-inline' from the HTTP header.

I followed the server side configuration based on https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/11031
and am running meteor 1.12.

How exactly do I dynamically set a `nonce=nonce_value` for all my inline tags when it's getting served?

Comment: hm, can you elaborate why this is needed, and show some example code? I've never heard of this and never had to do anything special for inline css.

Comment: I will update my question in a couple of hours when I'm in office thanks.